# Get blank value by using XPath

Tags: xpath

I'm using following code, but it just code blank string when i tried to get the link of images. Please help to fix it;

link page :  http://doisong.vnexpress.net/tin-tuc/suc-khoe/cuu-song-benh-nhan-ngung-tim-tac-mach-vanh-3035416.html

### Code worked for me, when i get the content (in tag p)

```
  foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='fck_detail width_common']/p/@*"))
        { 
            content = content + node.InnerText; 
        }
```

### Code when trying get the link of image (tag img)

```
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node2 in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='fck_detail width_common']/table/tbody/tr/td/img/@src")) 
                 {
                     string l1 = node2.InnerText;                        
                 }
```

they only return a blank string. Please refer the XML structure in below link
www.flickr.com/photos/37903269@N05/14821937739/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The img-tag has no inner text, so you won't get any result with this XPath.
It's just a guess, but try the following:

```
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node2 in 
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='fck_detail width_common']/table/tbody/tr/td/img[@src]")) 
             {
                 string  l1= img.Attributes["src"].Value;

             }
```

For a detailed explanation have a look at a similar question here:
 [Parse Image src with agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506588/parse-image-src-with-html-agilty-pack)